# Check to see if an element exists before passing a value to an array Jquery

Tags: jquery

Is there a way that I can check if an element exists before passing a value into an array with jquery.

For example I have the following code:

```
hyperlinks = new Array();
     $(slideshowThumbs).find('.caption').find('a:first').each(function() {
           hyperlinks.push($(this).attr('href'));
     });
```

Which passes and stores the values from a list of items and tells me what their href value is.

The problem that I have at the moment, is that if item 2 in my list does not contain a link, the value that is passed over at position 2 is in actual fact the value from item 3 and not 2.

What I want to do is see if there is an a:first inside of the caption container, and if there isnt pass a value to the array in place that I can subsequently do a check on later. in order to retain the list of items in the array the same as the list of items in my list.

Any ideas?

Many thanks

**EDIT:**
Thanks for your suggestions, though they didn't work straight off, they did get my brain to engage with what I was trying to do - coding with a cold, not always a good combination.

In any case my solution was as follows:

```
 hyperlinks = new Array();
 $(slideshowThumbs).find('.caption').each(function() {
      var elemExists = $(this).find('a:first');
      if (elemExists) {
          hyperlinks.push($(this).find('a:first').attr('href'));
      }
      else {
          hyperlinks.push('noLink');
      }
  });
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this

```
if ( $(this).attr('href') != '' )
     hyperlinks.push($(this).attr('href'));
else
    hyperlinks.push("no_link");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
hyperlinks = new Array();
     $(slideshowThumbs).find('.caption').find('a:first').each(function() {
           if ($(this).attr('href')) {
               // attribute exists
               hyperlinks.push($(this).attr('href'));
           }
     });
```